# Downloading Modules on Python

Tags: python, module

Im looking to download modules on Python but I seem to be running into some problems. Whenever I import a new module, an error always shows up. Here is an example of the code that I am using to download a module:

```
import openpyxl
```

and this is the error that shows up when I try to run this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/automation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl 
  File "/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY, PANDAS
  File "/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .strings import safe_string
  File "/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/strings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from math import isnan, isinf
ImportError: cannot import name 'isnan' from 'math' (/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/math.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If anyone knows what could be causing this please let me know.

Comment: `import` does not download a module, it *imports* it. To be able to import it you need to download and install it first.

Comment: Math module already exists. The problem can be in the code. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'isnan' from 'math' (/Users/jonathankent/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld/**math.py**)

It seems you have named your own module `math`. This shadows the built-in `math` module.

The error means that some other code wanted to import the built-in `math` module but found your module instead.

The simplest solution would be if you named your module differently.